# Linux kernel with ZFS eating my ram (2x of arc_max)

Tags: linux-kernel, zfs, out-of-memory

First up, It seems my kernel is using way too much ram

```
$ grep Slab /proc/meminfo
Slab:           21794184 kB
```

See [all of /proc/meminfo](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YWgpYZdCyz/)
and [/proc/slabinfo](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/b3wQrSykfs/)

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi        22Gi       3.6Gi       3.0Mi       5.1Gi       8.2Gi
Swap:         8.0Gi        12Mi       8.0Gi
```

I have zfs configured to use 12GiB of my memory, but it seems to somehow use a little more than that, causing arc_prune kthreads to **permanently max out all cores** despite zfs_arc_max not having changed since boot. I have 4x 8TB drives in raidz if that's relevant.
From `arc_summary.py`:

```
ARC Size:                               103.98% 12.48   GiB
        Target Size: (Adaptive)         100.00% 12.00   GiB
        Min Size (Hard Limit):          8.14%   999.96  MiB
        Max Size (High Water):          12:1    12.00   GiB
```

[See more ...](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hF4TDRgYkW/)

That still leaves about 9GiB of memory inexplicably lost to the kernel. I am pretty sure those problems (zfs maxing my cpu and the kernel eating memory) are related, which is why I post this as a single question.

I'm on ubuntu 20.04 LTS (linux 5.4.0-65-generic, zfs-0.8.3-1ubuntu12.7)

The problem goes away for a while after running `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` but that can hardly be the solution.

Whats going on? I have no idea where else to look for a hint.

Comment: https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: The ram is marked used and not buff/cache so this link is irrelevant to my question @Pourko